# Migration from weblogic 9.2 to 10.3.6 Failed to load bea_wls9_async_response.war

Tags: java, migration, weblogic

I have been migrating an application from weblogic 9.2 to weblogic 11 G (10.3.6). While starting new weblogic server, we are facing problems Also java version is upgraded from JDK1.5 to JDK 1.6

```
 <12 déc. 2016 10 h 04 CET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application E:\bea_10332\user_projects\domains\DOM\servers\Server\tmp\.internal\bea_wls9_async_response.war. Please make sure that the annotations are valid. The error is > 

<12 déc. 2016 10 h 04 CET> <Error> <J2EE> <LFR006114> <PhileasServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1481533463745> <BEA-160001> <Error deploying Internal Application: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'bea_wls9_async_response.war'
    weblogic.application.utils.StateChangeException: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'bea_wls9_async_response.war'
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:67)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BackgroundDeploymentService$BackgroundDeployAction.run(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:273)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused By: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'bea_wls9_async_response.war'
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BackgroundDeploymentService$1.next(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:348)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BackgroundDeploymentService$BackgroundDeployAction.run(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:273)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    Caused By: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:129)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.DefaultContainerBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultContainerBootstrap.java:51)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:147)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.WLSBootstrap.deploy(WLSBootstrap.java:111)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:114)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.bean.internal.AbstractBeanManager.initialize(AbstractBeanManager.java:52)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.WebComponentContributorBrokerImpl.initialize(WebComponentContributorBrokerImpl.java:69)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.initialize(WebComponentContributor.java:98)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1388)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:450)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BackgroundDeploymentService$1.next(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:348)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BackgroundDeploymentService$BackgroundDeployAction.run(BackgroundDeploymentService.java:273)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Do you have any idea what is the cause of this track or how can i resolve it please ?

thank you all.

Comment: See the comments here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149546/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-xerces-jaxp-documentbuilderfactoryi

Comment: The post in the link is about a ClassNotFound :/

Comment: The stack trace is truncated : "Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace" , so have a look at the log file if you want the whole of it .It has good chances of being the same problem as in the above link.

Comment: i changed the stacktrace with the full one

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should remove some annotations which may causing a problem and use web.xml mapping instead of annotations.

Comment: In the code the only annotation that i have are "param", "throws" and "return" i don't think it has an impact :/

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380411/difference-between-classpath-and-endorsed-directory)  was the solution of my probleme (add xerces.jar in endorsed folder)